# ServletConfig init() реализация

Tags: java, servlet, mockito

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно **реализовать метод init()** чтобы настроить ServletConfig? Очень нужно для тестирования junit + mockito, однако сервлеты запускаются в tomcat

```
@Test
void doPost() throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException {

    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

    when(request.getParameter("name")).thenReturn("some pills");
    when(request.getParameter("action")).thenReturn("headache");
    when(request.getParameter("form")).thenReturn("Liquid");
    when(request.getParameter("date")).thenReturn("2021-01-01");

    new AddServlet().doPost(request, response);

    Pills pill = new Pills("some pills", "headache", "Liquid",
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2021-01-01"));

    assertEquals(model.list().size(), 1);
    assertEquals(model.list().get(0), pill);

}
```

это тест-кейс

Comment: ServletConfig запускается и инициализаруется контейнером сервлетов. Задать параметры инициализации для ServletConfig вы можете в файле web.xml. Но если вы хотите выполнить некоторую инициализацию после того, как объект ServletConfig был создан контейнером сервлетов и до инициализации любого сервлета - используйте ServletContextListener.

Comment: просто дело в том, что нужно это сделать без запуска контейнера, проверить чисто этот кусок кода